# How can I change owner of a Registry Key to which I don't have access?

Tags: permissions, powershell, windows-registry

I ran into a bizarre issue when I upgraded some machines to Windows 10 where incorrect permissions on RuntimeBroker caused problems. I found [a solution online](https://shauncassells.wordpress.com/2015/09/28/windows-10-event-10016-fix-the-application-specific-permission-settings-do-not-grant-local-activation-permission-for-the-com-server-application-with-clsid-d63b10c5-bb46-4990-a94f-e40b9d520160-and-a/) that recommended changing permissions (first in the registry, then in DCOM configuration), and I'm trying to write a Powershell script to automate the process.

I'm trying to execute the following Powershell script, which should (in theory) do what I need to do. However, at the last command (Set-Acl) I get a SecurityException saying "Requested registry access is not allowed."

```
$path = "Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppID\{9CA88EE3-ACB7-47c8-AFC4-AB702511C276}";
$account = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Principal.NTAccount -ArgumentList 'Administrators';
$acl = Get-Acl -Path $path;
$acl.SetOwner($account);
Set-Acl -Path $path -AclObject $acl;
```

Presently the owner of that Registry Key is `NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller`, and I'm trying to change it to `Administrators`. **I am already running Powershell with Administrative privileges** but that obviously doesn't seem sufficient... my guess is that I'm running into a bit of a chicken and egg problem here.

If I manually edit the permissions of that key using `regedit`, I'm allowed to do that without problems. What is that regedit is doing differently from my script here? How can I accomplish this programmatically?

**UPDATE:** Per briantist's suggestion, I tried running these commands as SYSTEM using psexec. I saved the Powershell commands posted above into a file on my desktop called chowner.ps1 and then ran the following command:

```
PsExec64.exe -accepteula -d -i -s powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Users\User\Desktop\chowner.ps1
```

Unfortunately, I still get the same SecurityException message. I believe the reason is because not even SYSTEM has access rights to this particular Registry key; remember that TrustedInstaller owns it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Helge Kleins excellent Set-ACL CLI tool: https://helgeklein.com/setacl/.

```
SetACL.exe -on "hkcr\AppID\{9CA88EE3-ACB7-47c8-AFC4-AB702511C276}" -ot reg -actn setowner -ownr "n:S-1-5-32-544"
```

That one would do the trick I think. Must be run with elevated permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You should run your code as `SYSTEM`, a.k.a. `Local System`.

To do that, you can use `psexec` from SysInternals, or your could run the code as a scheduled task that is set to run as `SYSTEM`. That should allow you to change any permissions.

Comment: Ok, I just spent a lot of time trying to get it working with psexec, but I still end up with exactly the same error message (SecurityException: Requested registry access is not allowed). With psexec I'm running as SYSTEM.

Comment: @SoaperGEM hm that's surprising. I suppose as SYSTEM you could try to impersonate Trusted Installer, but I don't know of an easy way to accomplish that.

Comment: @SoaperGEM or what if instead of trying to change the owner first, see if you can add full control permissions, and then try to change the owner?

Comment: I can try it, but since both actions funnel through the same command (Set-Acl) I would immediately suspect I'll run into the same issue.

Comment: @SoaperGEM possibly, but SYSTEM is specially privileged, or at least should be; I figured it would be worth a try.

Comment: Confirmed: same error